# Resizing an image on server or an android phone which is better

Tags: android

Will it be better and more efficient to resize an image on the server and send it to the phone rather than resizing the image on the phone itself ?. For example i have an image stored in different resolution for xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi and ldpi, i then detect the device density at runtime and request the appropriate image. Will there be any noticeable performance

Comment: If you are sending image to server, its better to resize it on phone whereas if you are downloading, you do it better on server side

Answer (score 0):

If you send a image to server you must go over data connection. 
if your link not optimal the user have to wait for a long time.
A moderen Smartphone has enough power to recreate or resize a image.

Comment: the images won't be stored on the phone. i wanted to do automatic resizing first instead of sending the file to the phone like that for resizing.